# How do I copy portion of <p> text onClick

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I have an HTML document with a 'p' element which I would like a portion of copied to the clipboard when the whole element is clicked.

```
<p class="pageID"><strong>Page ID: </strong>#A16</p>
```

Which returns: **PageID:** #A16

I want to have it so when I click anywhere on this line the page ID (#A16) is copied to the clipboard but nothing else. I've seen some similar questions on here and tried a bunch of different JavaScript solutions but nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: wrapping the portion you want to copy would make this 100% easier

Comment: _"tried a bunch of different JavaScript solutions but nothing is working"_ Post this please. We need a [mcve] to see where things didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<p class="pageID"><strong>Page ID: </strong><span id="toCopy">#A16</span></p>

<script>
document.querySelector(".pageID").addEventListener('click', function() {
   var temp_input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   temp_input.value = document.querySelector('#toCopy').innerHTML;
   temp_input.select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
});
</script>
```

No jQuery needed!

Comment: You just need to create an input element, but don't need to append it to the document.

Comment: You’re right thanks for the catch! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of the head, I'd wrap whatever you're trying to copy into it's own element and copy the text of the element.

ex: `<p class="pageID"><strong>Page ID: </strong><span class="your-class-name">#A16</span></p>`

Comment: Where is the copy part?

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap that text in element with some id and then focus on it and copy like this

```
var el = document.getElementById("myText");
el.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: The issue is `select()` only works with text fields.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful? https://dev.to/mornir/-how-to-easily-copy-text-to-clipboard-a1a

Comment: Or you can create temporary textarea or input and copy from it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="myId"><p class="pageID" id="myElement"><strong>Page ID: </strong>#A16</p></div>

<script>
$('#myId').onClick(function() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myElement");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value); // do whatever you want with this text.
});
</script>
```